# PC crashes with debug LEDs saying "CPU not detected" when I try to run the game: Valorant. But it can run the game with integrated GPU

Tags: windows-10, cpu, crash, gpu

My graphics card is GTX 1650. My CPU is core i5 7400. My motherboard is MSI B250I gaming pro ac. I have the latest drivers for everything. Game used to run perfectly until last night. I had to move my pc from one room to another and suddenly this problem started happening. Everything works fine as expected, except for Valorant. I can do my coding, studying, etc. without any problem.

But when I start Valorant, within a couple seconds the monitor says no video input. It sounds like the turning off but some parts of the computer stay running. The CPU and GPU fans keep spinning. Hard disks keep spinning. RGB stuff keep working. But the debug LED indicates "CPU not detected" (according to manual from MSI website). But no buttons or inputs work. Even the restart button on the front of the casing doesn't work. I have to turn the power off and on again to restart the pc.

Since it says no video output, I tried to see if the problem is with the GPU (although the debug LEDs say "CPU not detected"). I removed the graphics card and tried to run Valorant with the integrated graphics adapter (Intel HD 630). It ran fine without issue (not counting 30 fps max as an issue here). I played some deathmatches just to make sure the game was not the problem.

I later uninstalled the graphics driver using DDU and reinstalled the latest one again. But the problem persists. I uninstalled and reinstalled Valorant too. Didn't help.

Does anyone have any idea or suggestion that I can try? I can't even pinpoint the problem in order to begin troubleshooting. Runs fine without GPU when CPU is doing all the work. But crashes with GPU installed and says "CPU not detected" when most of the workload is alleviated off of the CPU. Please help, thanks!

Comment: I assume you have since reinstalled the GPU and still have the problem?

Comment: If you have System Restore enabled, rollback to before the problem happened. If the problem is now gone, note down via Device Manager your exact version of display driver for the GTX.